# Apache 403 error, (13)Permission denied: access to / denied, Fedora 16

Tags: apache, fedora

I've just set up apache on my Fedora 16. And i can't get my vhosts working!

Though localhost/phpmyadmin works fine..

I got this in my httpd.conf

```
<Directory /home/renat/www>
AllowOverride All
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName fabbro.fm
    DocumentRoot /home/renat/www/fabbro
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything is fine with permissions too:

```
    ls -l
    drwxr-xr-x. 32 renat renat 4096 янв.   7 16:12 www
```

And i've got 403 error when try to access fabbro.fm
error_log says:

```
[client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

What do i have to do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I solved this problem!
Apache could not access those directories because of the SELinux security settings.
All i had to do is to apply this command to the directory in the path to document root:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t
```

Comment: I get this error, when I try to apply this on my root directory.

chcon: missing operand
Try 'chcon --help' for more information.

Comment: chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t .  or chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/fileOrDirectory

Comment: What this line does? I got "chcon: missing operand" after writing it

Comment: chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t with the -R will recursively apply this to the entire directory contents. This worked for me on CentOS 6.6 w/ Apache 2.4.

Comment: Saved 3-4 hours of my life!

Answer (score 2):

I had a SELinux issue.  I first tried `chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t` but that didn't fix it.  After that I did `setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1` and it worked.  I don't know if the first command was necessary or only the second.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

> [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied

makes me think there is a misconfiguration somewhere  - a second `VirtualHost` for example, or a global `DocumentRoot` definition.

That second definition is somehow setting `DocumentRoot`  to the *system's* root directory. Apache is right to deny that.

You need to find the definition that is causing this, and remove it.

Comment: well i don't think so, can you have a look plz?
[link](http://pastebin.com/Ck1pEtst)

Comment: @mennanov strange, that looks okay. Do you have any .htaccess files with Alias rules or something like that?

Comment: .htaccess no, but conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf has alias operators but i don't think it is a problem

Comment: What other confs do you have in there?

Comment: i have one more vhost. It is similar to that one but has another documentroot

Comment: Also i've just commented out all Include operators in httpd.conf (so nothing was included besided vhosts) but got the same result..

Comment: @mennanov well, I'm fairly sure that the `/` in the error message points to the actual root directory of the filesystem. At least in all Apache versions I've worked with, there is always the full path in the message. I'm not 100% sure, but think there must be some command somewhere that changes the document root to `/` - for whatever reason....

Comment: could this be a problem with selinux?

Answer (score 1):

I had to run the following to make it work. chcon and setsebool mentioned earlier did not help.

> firewall-cmd --add-service=http

This is on Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug), btw.

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod +x /home/"user"
```