# 403 Error with OpenCPU on ubuntu

Tags: r, opencpu

Firefox can't find the file at /R/call/base/identity/json.
I am running openCPU
I can go to

127.0.0.1

it goes to
127.0.0.1/pages/

And then I go to the example API and I try out the buttons to run example codes and it tells me
You dont have permission to access /r/pub/ggplot2/qplot/pdf

Also

```
Request failed: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /R/call/opencpu.demo/nabel/save
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Hmmz did you have any pre-existing apache configurations?

Comment: Yes I had rApache previously installed, I decided to reinstall ubuntu 12.4 on my virtualbox and Im going to tell you what happens when I follow gmlime's insight

Comment: I fixed it by reinstalling ubuntu and it was because I had a mangled httpd.conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled ubuntu on virtualbox and followed the directions carefully on opencpu and it works out of the box

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that can cause this issue, your os setup might be too secure for example you are SELinux  , you might have to chown or chmod the permissions on the file system, or you might have to reconfig apache itself.

Here are some resources to help solve the problem:

If you need to check file permisions:
http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied
and that demostrates how to use namei:

```
namei -m /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/foo/bar.html
```

To see what is going on.

---

This dicussses a solution for SELinux causing a problem with the apaceh permisssions:

[Apache 403 error, (13)Permission denied: access to / denied, Fedora 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816836/apache-403-error-13permission-denied-access-to-denied-fedora-16)

Essesstiaally you apply `chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t` to every directory in the path to the document root.

---

Since you don't seem to be running cgi or php it probably isn't a problem with loosing those permissions, but if it is you should make the http.conf for apache allows executing scripts and that they are in an appropriate directory.

Comment: Thank you gmlime for helping me I want to give you something for answering this question but, I decided to write out how i solved it for others. What can I do to your post?